# How do I connect MS Access to an Azure SQL Database table using VBA?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ms-access

I have a procedure in an Access database that loops through a list of tables and views, if they exist it deletes them, and then reconnects to the table or view on the server.  Works great on on-site MS SQL, can't get it to work with Azure SQL.

I've installed the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server but keep hitting the same error - *"Could not find installable ISAM"*.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Edit question to show your code and explain why duplicate thread does not resolve issue.

Comment: Well, before I start using complex code, I would connect manually using the UI - and get that working first. If you can't get a working connection from the UI, then it FOR SURE your code not going to work - right? I would get the connection working without any code and just the UI - once that works, then you can look at the table def connection string and verify that you using the same connection string in code. Once you get that working then in debug/immdiate window just go ? currentDB.tableDefs("linked table").Conneciton